# Is the Projection of a Partition of a Product Space always Disjoint in at least one Factor Space?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I came across this while attempting to prove that factor spaces being connected implies the product space being connected; in particular when trying to prove the contrapositive.

The proposition to be proven is similar to the one stated in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1516553/326036) (which is false) but with a couple extra hypotheses (i.e. that the sets in the partition of the product space be open):

Let $(X_1, \tau_1), \ldots, (X_n, \tau_n)$ be topological spaces, and let $(\mathcal{X}, \tau)$ be the (finite) product space where $\mathcal{X} = \prod_{i = 1}^n X_i$ and $\tau$ is the corresponding product topology. Let $\pi_i$ denote the canonical projection from $\mathcal{X}$ to $X_i$. Let $\{U, V\}$ be a partition of $\mathcal{X}$ where $U, V \in \tau$ ($U$ and $V$ are open in the product space). Define $U_i = \pi_i[U]$, $V_i = \pi_i[V]$ for each $i \in [n]$. Then there exists an $i \in [n]$ such that $U_i$ and $V_i$ are disjoint.

If this is true, then I can finish the proof I have got so far, but I haven't been able to prove or disprove this lemma. Is this true?

---

This is my visualisation of one particular example where this is true, just to illustrate what the lemma is saying:

[image: illustration]

Comment: Suppose $X_1=X_2=\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Let $U=\{(a,b)\in X_1\times X_2:a=b\}$ and $V= \{(a,b)\in X_1\times X_2:a\neq b\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "lemma" is false, as Andreas' counterexample (in the comment) shows.

But you don't need it: if $X=\prod_i X_i$ is connected, all $X_i$ are continuous images of $X$ under the projection maps so are all connected as continuous images of connected spaces are connected.

For the reverse, a bit more work is needed; start with two spaces and extend by induction, e.g.